# How to inject ngCookies into provider()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying, without success, to inject the Angular JS ngCookie module and $cookies service into an Angular Provider.  Can someone please explain the lac of success?

When I inject ngCookies into the Provider

```
angular.module('loginService', [])
.provider('loginService', function () {
    var userToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken'),
        errorState = 'app.error',
        logoutState = 'app.home';

    this.$get = function ($rootScope, $http, $q, $state) {

        /**
         * Low-level, private functions.
         */
        var setHeaders = function (token) {
            if (!token) {
                delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Token'];
                return;
            }
            $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Token'] = token.toString();
        };
...
});
```

like so:

```
angular.module('loginService', ['ngCookies'])
.provider('loginService', ['$cookies', function ($cookies) {
    var userToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken'),
        errorState = 'app.error',
        logoutState = 'app.home';
```

I get an error:

```
Unknown provider: $cookies
```

I suspect that I can't inject Services into Providers?  My issue is that I am calling a web service which is returning a session id as a Set-Cookie header.  I'd like to grab the ss-id but can't seem to retrieve it from the response header so thought I'd get it from the cookie instead.

I'm open to better alternatives though...

Comment: You cannot inject factories and services to providers.

Comment: You can only inject $cookies in your $get function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only inject other providers into a provider. It is only possible to inject a service in the public functions or config block of the provider.